# Display certain items from array of objects in recyclerview

Tags: json, object, android-recyclerview, nested, retrofit2

From the code below, I want to display `request_id`, `request_title`, `status`, `no of trucks` in `recyclerview` using retrofit 2.0. How to do this?

Here is my nested array of objects.

```
 [
        {
            "id": 96,
            "request_id": 24365,
            "request_title": "tsfghjjlfdsg;lhj",
            "transport_co_id": 1,
            "status": 1,
            "truck_info": [
                {
                    "driver_mobile": 2147483647,
                    "driver_name": "dsdsd",
                    "truck_no": 1111
                },
                {
                    "driver_mobile": 2147483647,
                    "driver_name": "add",
                    "truck_no": 727
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 97,
            "request_id": "test123",
            "request_title": "test title",
            "transport_co_id": 1,
            "status": 1,
            "truck_info": [
                {
                    "driver_mobile": 2147483647,
                    "driver_name": "dsdsd",
                    "truck_no": 1111
                },
                {
                    "driver_mobile": 2147483647,
                    "driver_name": "add",
                    "truck_no": 1
                }
            ]
         }   
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create retrofit interface , class

```
public class ChampApiClient {

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }

}
```

Comment: email me il  will send you the working code sumeethgowda2{at}gmail

Comment: if you need anything in android or kotlin we would help you out.